# How to determine two implicit conversion sequences preferred than each other for overload resolution?

Tags: c++, c++11, language-lawyer

I want to question about overload resolution accompanying an implicit type conversion. This question refers cppreference [1](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/implicit_conversion) and [2](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/overload_resolution).

It seems that an implicit conversion sequence has at most three steps to convert an type `T1`(argument type) to `T2`(parameter type):

1. zero or one standard conversion sequence;
2. <del>zero or one user-defined conversion; (</del> I want to ignore this step because it isn't related to this question.)
3. zero or one standard conversion sequence.

An implicit conversion sequence can be categorized as one of:

- a standard conversion sequence (I am interested this fundamental type conversions case only.)
- <del>a user-defined conversion sequence</del>
- <del>an ellipsis conversion sequence</del>

And, each type of standard conversion sequence is assigned one of three ranks:

1. *Exact match* : no conversion required, lvalue-to-rvalue conversion, qualification conversion, function pointer conversion, user-defined conversion of class type to the same class
2. *Promotion* : integral promotion, floating-point promotion
3. *Conversion* : integral conversion, floating-point conversion, floating-integral conversion, pointer conversion, pointer-to-member conversion, boolean conversion, user-defined conversion of a derived class to its base

And,

> The rank of the standard conversion sequence is the worst of the ranks of the standard conversions it holds.

I think there will be a case where two implicit conversion sequences have its constituent standard conversion sequence steps which have different ranks each other. So, IMHO it is hard for me to determine which implicit conversion sequence is preferred than the other.

For example(Unfortunately, i couldn't come up with a concrete example.),

An implicit conversion sequence (**A**) consists of

1. standard conversion sequence (**A-1**) which is rank *promotion*.
2. no user-defined conversion sequence
3. standard conversion sequence (**A-2**) which is rank *conversion*.

The other implicit conversion sequence (**B**) consists of

1. standard conversion sequence (**B-1**) which is rank *conversion*.
2. no user-defined conversion sequence
3. standard conversion sequence (**B-2**) which is rank *promotion*.

In this case, **A-1** is preferred than **B-1** but **B-2** is preferred than **A-2**. So, each of **A** and **B** have own preferences. -> ambiguous call?

OR... **A-1** and **B-1** should be compared first than **A-2** and **B-2**. So, should we stop comparing each other here for greedy comparison? -> The **A** is chosen?

---

UPDATE: To explain my understanding about these concept...

```cpp
// [ what is overall rank for standard coversion sequence n  ]
// [          standard conversion sequence n(up to 2)        ]
// [     each conversion's rank in a std conv sequence n     ]
// [ what conversions are performed in a std conv sequence n ]
// [    how source type T1 is converted to target type T2    ]

// [            promotion                ][       exact match    ]
// [          std conv seq1              ][     std conv seq2    ]
// [  promotion  |     exact match       ][        exact match   ]
// [  promotion  |  const qualification  ][     no conversion    ]
// [char   ->   int    ->   const int    ->        const int     ]
void f(const int){
    std::cout << "f(const int)" << std::endl;
}

// [   promotion   ][                conversion                  ]
// [ std conv seq1 ][               std conv seq2                ]
// [   promotion   ||      conversion      |     exact match     ]
// [   promotion   ||  integral conversion, const qualification  ]
// [char   ->     int       ->     long    ->    const long      ]
void f(const long){
    std::cout << "f(const long)" << std::endl;
}

int main() {
    // For the first sequence, the two functions have same 2nd rank, 'promotion'.
    // So, we couldn't determine which function will be called yet.
    // But, for the second sequence, the former has 1st rank 'exact match'
    // and the latter has 3rd rank 'conversion'. So the former will be called.
    f('c'); // prints "f(const int)"
}
```

Comment: If A-1 is an exact match, how would A-2 be non-exact? A conversion either is an exact match or it requires some conversion to the type. It cannot be *both*.

Comment: The comparison here with A and B, does it refer to two different overloads of a function where the argument could be converted in 2 different ways or are you refering to a function with two arguments where each parameter has a different conversion?

Comment: @super For one function call, there exist two viable overload functions(In your comment, the former case). Each function involves its own implicit conversion. For the simplicity, the function has only one parameter.

Comment: @NicolBolas The term *exact match* is not for designating best viable function. It is used for implicit conversion's rank. Please refer [Ranking_of_implicit_conversion_sequences](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/overload_resolution#Ranking_of_implicit_conversion_sequences)

Comment: @rosshjb: But the term "exact match" represents a relationship between the source and destination type. If A-1 is an "exact match," that means the source type and the destination type *are the same*. So how could there be a later conversion match?

Comment: @NicolBolas Even though A-1 has rank *exact match*, when A-2 has rank *conversion*, the overall rank should be *conversion*, not *exact match*. From the same link in the above comment, `The rank of the standard conversion sequence is the worst of the ranks of the standard conversions it holds (there may be up to three conversions)`

Comment: @rosshjb: What I'm saying is that if A-1 is an exact match, *there can be no later conversion*. The hypothetical you have proposed *cannot happen*. If you're converting from int to int, that is an exact match. A-1 is exact match, and A-2 is exact match.

Comment: @NicolBolas What about changing the *exact match* rank to *conversion* rank and *conversion* rank to *promotion*? I mean the point here is not about which rank is *exact match*, IMHO.

Comment: @rosshjb: I no longer understand what you're talking about. Conversion sequences exist to get from type X to type Y. Each conversion step in that sequence does one of the following: turns X into Y, turns X into X2, or does nothing because X is already Y. If X is already Y, all later conversions are exact because *we're already at the destination*. Conversion sequences are not arbitrarily built; they're not every path to the goal.

Comment: @NicolBolas I updated my question to talk about this issue. The two cases all have *exact match*.

Comment: @rosshjb: `char` is not `int`, so "exact match" cannot happen on the first conversion.

Comment: @NicolBolas I didn't say `char` is `int`. The type `char` is promoted to `int` — [Integral promotion](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/implicit_conversion#Integral_promotion)

Comment: @rosshjb: Then your example doesn't match your case **A**. In **A**, you start with an exact match, but later do some conversion. Your example doesn't do that. So show an example where **A** exists.

Comment: @NicolBolas The `const` qualification to a type is categorized as a conversion which has *exact match* **rank**.  Refer [here](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/overload_resolution#Ranking_of_implicit_conversion_sequences) .The updated example is just for explaining basic concept. I have to come up with a matched example. But i couldn't yet. I don't understand why you focus the term *exact match*. Let's replace the A-1's rank to *promotion* rank and B-2's rank to *promotion* rank. Hold a second. I will update question to reflect this.

Answer (score 0):

Cppreference is a useful reference site, but it is not the C++ standard. It has mostly accurate information, but in boiling down the complexities of the standard, some details can be lost around the margins.

I will be citing C++17 (since I don't have a C++11 website I can link to), but the wording has not meaningfully changed.

[over.best.ics]/3 [defines an implicit conversion sequence as](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/over.best.ics#3):

> A well-formed implicit conversion sequence is one of the following forms:
>
> - a standard conversion sequence,
> - a user-defined conversion sequence, or
> - an ellipsis conversion sequence.

This is more-or-less what Cppreference says, but here it is made more explicit that you either have precisely *one* standard conversion sequence or you have precisely *one* user-defined conversion. The user-defined conversion *itself* [includes two standard conversion sequences](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/over.ics.user):

> A user-defined conversion sequence consists of an initial standard conversion sequence followed by a user-defined conversion ([class.conv]) followed by a second standard conversion sequence.

Cppreference makes it seem like you can have two standard conversion sequences *without* a user-defined conversion, but you cannot. If there is no user-defined conversion in play, you have only one standard conversion.

Don't try to read Cppreference as the legal definition of C++. Think of it more as "C++ works mostly like this". If you need legalistic detail (and in most cases, you *don't*. *Especially* around overload resolution. Knowing too much about this can make you a bad programmer), then you have to go to the standard.

Comment: Thanks. I can agree about an implicit conversion sequence as you said. Especially, `If there is no user-defined conversion in play, you have only one standard conversion.` I have a question. According to your answer, how should a call `f('c')` to `void f(long)` be processed? Is the conversion `char` to `long` an integral promotion or integral conversion? According to your answer, the `char` can't be promoted to `int` first because the `int` should be converted to `long` again. As you said, there is only one std conv seq, and the conversion and promotion can't happen in one sequence at once.

Comment: @rosshjb: "*the conversion and promotion can't happen in one sequence.*" A conversion from `char` to `long` is an integral conversion. There's no "promotion to `int`". Also, you should not write code where it *matters* at all to the user.

Comment: `a standard conversion sequence is either the Identity conversion by itself (that is, no conversion) or consists of one to three conversions from the other four categories. At most one conversion from each category is allowed in a single standard conversion sequence.` — [over.ics.scs/3](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/over.ics.scs). Does `A conversion from char to long is an integral conversion.` mean that `f('c')` would call `void f(long)` through integral conversion `char` to `long`?

Comment: @rosshjb: Then what's your question? `char` gets promoted to `int`, then converted to `long`. And again, *why does it matter*? What does this kind of detail mongering get you? You can pass `char` to any function taking most integer types. That's what you need to know.

Comment: I commented wrong link. The correct link is [here](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4140/over.ics.scs) and [here](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4140/conv). The (1.2) in the latter link said that integral promotions and integral conversions can't happen at the same time. But the former link said that the two can happen at the same time. weired.